# Serializer Error When Using Rest Framework to Serialize Nested Objects from Model

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-serializer

I have seen some related posts, but I am not sure what I need to do.

I have set up a view to serialize my test model which has nested models. I have set up the serializers, but I get the error "Got AttributeError when attempting to get a value for field `Question` on serializer `TestSerializer`.\nThe serializer field might be named incorrectly".

My Serializers:

```
class AnswerSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Answer
        fields = ('id', 'number', 'text', 'iscorrect')

class QuestionSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    answer = AnswerSerializer()

    class Meta:
        model = Question
        fields = ('id', 'number', 'text', 'answer')
        related_object = 'answer'

class TestSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    question = QuestionSerializer()

    class Meta:
        model = Test
        fields = ('id', 'name', 'question')
        related_object = 'question'
```

My Models:

```
class Test(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.PROTECT)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255,default='',blank=False)
    datecreated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

class Question(models.Model):
    test = models.ForeignKey(Test, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    text = models.CharField(max_length=255,default='',blank=False)
    number = models.IntegerField()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.text

class Answer(models.Model):
    question = models.ForeignKey(Question, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    text = models.CharField(max_length=255,default='',blank=False)
    number = models.IntegerField()
    iscorrect = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.text
```

The call from the view:

```
serializer = TestSerializer(test, many=True)
```

Comment: try using a different variable name "question" for  
**question = QuestionSerializer()**

Comment: Would the new variable name also be reflected in the fields and related_object?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have set the related_name in the foreign key other wise default related name is {model_name}_set.

```
class Question(models.Model):
  test = models.ForeignKey(Test, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='questions')
  text = models.CharField(max_length=255,default='',blank=False)
  number = models.IntegerField()

  def __str__(self):
     return self.text
```

in serializer you can access that fields

```
class TestSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
  questions = QuestionSerializer(many=True)

  class Meta:
    model = Test
    fields = ('id', 'name', 'question')
    related_object = 'question'
```

Comment: Many thanks, I used question_set and replaced question (serializer) with that as well as question in fields. That's working now, thanks for your help with this.